# Ansible EC2 Hosts Script Missing Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ansible

For some reason, ansible's ec2 hosts is missing instances. ec2-describe-instances returns the correct instances, but /etc/ansible/hosts does not:

```
[root@or-manage ec2-user]# ec2-describe-instances | grep seed
TAG     instance        i-ff0b2f36      Name    cass-uat-seed
[root@or-manage ec2-user]# /etc/ansible/hosts | grep seed
[root@or-manage ec2-user]#
```

You can see that ec2-describe-instances has the instance with the tag I'm looking for, but ansible hosts does not.

Why is that instance not in there for /etc/ansible/hosts?

---

Note: At first, I thought it was `/etc/ansible/hosts` using the wrong region, but I turned up the boto debug and it *IS* the correct region:

`send: 'POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 221\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nHost: ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

---

Update 1:

I've noticed that any instances without a public IP do not appear in the /etc/ansible/hosts list.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 5):

I had to tweak the following knobs (in `/etc/ansible/ec2.ini`):

```
# This is the normal destination variable to use. If you are running Ansible
# from outside EC2, then 'public_dns_name' makes the most sense. If you are
# running Ansible from within EC2, then perhaps you want to use the internal
# address, and should set this to 'private_dns_name'. The key of an EC2 tag
# may optionally be used; however the boto instance variables hold precedence
# in the event of a collision.
destination_variable = private_dns_name

# For server inside a VPC, using DNS names may not make sense. When an instance
# has 'subnet_id' set, this variable is used. If the subnet is public, setting
# this to 'ip_address' will return the public IP address. For instances in a
# private subnet, this should be set to 'private_ip_address', and Ansible must
# be run from within EC2. The key of an EC2 tag may optionally be used; however
# the boto instance variables hold precedence in the event of a collision.
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address
```

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks. I am guessing your Ansible management node is hosted in the same VPC that you are deploying to correct? It seems changing to this makes the ec2.py file return private IPs.

Comment: If you make a change, don't forget to change the cache value "cache_max_age" or you will see the same results.